# iOS 7 customize text color of quick view launched from document interaction controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone app.
I have set the color of the navigation bar to blue, and the text to white using

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                      nil]];
```

in the delegate.

In a view controller I use a Document interaction controller to share a pdf, but when I choose to print it, or to open with Quick Look, those apps are presented with the standard white navigation bar of the system, but with the text in white, which makes the title and the buttons unreadable.. how can i fix this?
I've already tried to take a look at the methods of the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, but I couldn't find a solution..

This is how the print view appears:
[image: How the print view appears, with white title over white bar]

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 you can set `UINavigationBar` color by calling this in delegate class,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:95.0f/255.0f blue:156.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
```

And of course the title color by calling this,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
```

But always make sure when you set `UINavigationBar` color, check the os compatibility wheres we have to use different method in iOS 6 and below, And you can achieve that like this,

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:95.0f/255.0f blue:156.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    }else{
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:95.0f/255.0f blue:156.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    }
```

Comment: How can I use this code in the "print controller"? in the controller that presents the Document Interaction Controller, the barTintColor and the TintColor are correct. I need to change the color of them in the Print Controller and in Quick Look...

Comment: This code basically do the trick, Check this sample with my given code pasted in to the delegate class. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PrintPhoto/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010366